# Css for Link buttons (no text) in page header , using Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Hey I hve made this sample page for me http://jsfiddle.net/9S3a3/12/ , if we have a look at buttons , there is a slight shadow below them , i want to remove those shadows look, i tried resizing margin padding things but not able to do so . Any solution to this ??

----------**Edit**----------

I was talking about back button and gear button , see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMTej.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `box-shadow`s are applied using the `.ui-shadow` class. So editing that CSS class like below will remove the shadows:

```
<style>
[data-role="header"] a.ui-shadow {
    box-shadow: none ;
}
</style>
```

This will remove the `box-shadow` for any link with the `.ui-shadow` class that is located inside the `data-role="header"` element.

Here is a link to an updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9S3a3/14/

On a side note, I remove the text and box shadow for most elements as it helps improve performance on mobile devices quite a lot.

Comment: thanks , can u help me with this question as well ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602262/how-to-make-fixed-header-using-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get which buttons are you asking about, however, correct me if I am wrong. Add

```
#nav_header {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

to your CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/9S3a3/13/) to remove the shadow (border) under the `Featured`, `Near`, `New` buttons.